# Cannot make server-side events working with nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

I cannot get the SSE to work on my nodejs/express aplication. I have these codes:

```
app.get('/sse', function (pedido, resposta) {
   resposta.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });
  resposta.write('\n');
  global.res = resposta;
  setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    global.res.write('id: ' + d.getMilliseconds() + '\n');
    global.res.write('data:' + new Date() + '\n\n'); 
  }, 5000);
});
```

On the client side:

```
//...
var source = new EventSource('/sse');
source.onmessage = function (event) {
 document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = event.data;
};
//...
```

But it does not work. On the client browser, it appear the EvenetSource called but it occurs a timeout. On the server, if i insert console.logs(every where) i can see that it is working. Something is missing and i do not understand why. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: you need to write the end() into the response stream. something like  resposta.end(); so that the response is send back to the client. or use resposta.send();  (or does this in the global part)

Comment: your are right! I was missing the obvious! global.res.end();

Comment: how to control the event name to reply only to each event instead to all? Also, if i write a console.log( before the setInterval, i writes to the log every time the setInterval is trigger, meaning that the client browser is repeating the http get request?

Comment: if you want to PUSH events from the server to the client (every so many seconds) then take a look at using socket.io http://socket.io/ which does exactly that (your client then subscribes to named events pushed by the server). If you want to pass in parameters then look at https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters for examples of POST and GET

Answer (score 2):

I was missing:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    global.res.write('id: ' + d.getMilliseconds() + '\n');
    global.res.write('data:' + new Date() + '\n\n'); 
}, 5000);setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    global.res.write('id: ' + d.getMilliseconds() + '\n');
    global.res.write('data:' + new Date() + '\n\n'); 
    resposta.end(); // was missing this
}, 5000);
```

Thank you [Code Uniquely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1582029/code-uniquely)